# Android detect when the car is slowing down and parking

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors

In car is expected to be used the GPS. That has a speed, but sometimes at low speed 5 km/h?: searching for parking place it shows 0 for speed - and the car is moving!

How can I detect the car is stopped?

GPS speed = 0 and:

- Accelerometer change differences in 3-10 sec doesn't reach  a certain level?
- Some devices has magnetic field sensor ( compass ) but not all. Heading to magnetic north changes in an interval ( 3- 10 sec) doesn't reach a certain level?

I can require min OS version Android 4.0, if it helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you are keeping device in deck,just check accelerometer readings,if you want to hold the phone in hand its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

**How can I detect the car is stopped?**

I believe you can fire an event every 30 seconds(or more) to check the lat/long. if Lat & long doesn't matched to previous Lat/Long then surely is car moved to some place but if it don't then i believe car is stopped.

Comment: +1, good point, unless you drive in a subterain  garage and loose GPS signal, or accuracy decreased from 3meter to 100m :)